Performance gain after index cleanup in SQL Server
I have a huge production environment - around 1.5 TB database size.
We had monitored index usage for around 6 months and found 20 indexes where seeks are 0. We decided to drop them, but client wants us to quantify the performance gain which we can get from this.
As this is a huge system and found indexes are smaller ones, is there a way to compare performance of system after dropping these indexes? If no queries are using these indexes, then how can this be quantified? Please suggest.
